# Meaning of 活该 臭死她才好?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, mandarin

They are talking about a girl in an embarrassing video that went viral
活该 臭死她才好
"Serves her right..." I don't get the rest. 
Edit: There's nothing about a smelly environment in the video but more the emphasis that her reputation is tarnished making people avoid her. Does it still mean smell to death?

Answer (score 1):

臭 : (n)stink; (adj)stinking; smelly

臭 here is acting as a verb, meaning "to subject ones to stinking smell"

> 臭死她才好 --> "it is right to stink her to death (kill her with stinking smell)"

Foul smell is not a lethal substance, the phrase is just an expression, similar to "悶死她 (bore her to death)"  where "悶 (bore)" is used as a verb for "subject one to boredom"

*Side note: 臭 stinking can be used as an adjective for derogatory word, e.g. 小子(kid) --> 臭小子(stinky kid)  = 可惡的小子 (damn kid)*

Answer (score 1):

臭死她才好 - let her smell/suffer the stinky smell to death. An unsympathetic comment towards a girl/woman who is in a stinky environment, or encounters something that has a bad smell (like dead fish, or fart).

**Add after "Edit"**:

It means she is tangled in an eye-catching, controversial matter/event that tarnishes her reputation. This matter/event has the effect that is similar to dirt her with stinky stuff and letting her suffer the bad consequence/smell.

Answer (score 1):

What did she do, poor waif?

活该臭死她才好。
She deserves death by stench!